Channel is being closed exception. Spring Boot 3.1.2 SFTP integration
we are experiencing Channel is being closed issue with Spring Boot 3 SFTP integration.
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: Channel is being closed
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.DefaultSftpClient.receive(DefaultSftpClient.java:319)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.response(AbstractSftpClient.java:181)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.rpc(AbstractSftpClient.java:169)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkHandle(AbstractSftpClient.java:290)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.open(AbstractSftpClient.java:589)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.SftpOutputStreamAsync.<init>(SftpOutputStreamAsync.java:63)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.write(AbstractSftpClient.java:1213)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient.write(SftpClient.java:940)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient.write(SftpClient.java:936)

this error happens from time to time when we execute around 50 requests to save a file to a SFTP server. The files itself is not big, up to 10Kb. To write a file we use SftpRemoteFileTemplate which is configured like this:
@Bean
public SftpRemoteFileTemplate remoteFileTemplate(SFTPConfig sftpConfig) {
    SshClient sshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
    CoreModuleProperties.PREFERRED_AUTHS.set(sshClient, "password");
    sshClient.addPasswordIdentity(sftpConfig.password());

    DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(sshClient, true);
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setHost(sftpConfig.hostname());
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setUser(sftpConfig.user());
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPort(sftpConfig.port());
    return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(defaultSftpSessionFactory);
}

void write(String filePath, byte[] fileData) {
    sftpRemoteFileTemplate.execute((session) -> {
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
        session.write(inputStream, filePath);
    });
}

We have tried to change pool size
SftpModuleProperties.POOL_SIZE.set(sshClient, <some number, 2, 4, 6, etc>);

and different IO service factory
MinaServiceFactoryFactory minaServiceFactoryFactory = new MinaServiceFactoryFactory();
sshClient.setIoServiceFactoryFactory(minaServiceFactoryFactory);

Also when we set the shared session flag to false we do not get Channel is being closed issue, but get Connection reset by peer because the service spawns a lot of sessions and the SFTP server starts to refuse a new one at some point of time
DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(sshClient, false);

The same code works fine using SB 2.x under the same load.
Any hints on where we should look to fix the problem?
Thanks

you can try this..
@Bean
public InitializingBean initializingBean(SftpRemoteFileTemplate template) {
    return () -> template
        .execute(session -> {
            try {
                session.isOpen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("error initializingBean:{}", e);
            }
            return null;
        });
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
